# jamierumbelow MY_Model: selecting db doesn't work

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm using the fantastic MY_Model of Jamie Rumbelow, it's very fast and easy to use on the default db configuration. But when I want to use a secondary configuration the problems cames out.

As the reference suggest, I added in the model

```
public $_db_group = 'db_config_name';
```

But when I execute any command, the result is:

```
Error Number: 1146
Table 'DEFAULT_db_name.table_name' doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM (`table_name`)
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: its much improved my model now.

Answer (score 0):

in your model you have to define $_db_group as public

```
public $_db_group = 'group_name';
```

check the [model doc](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model)

Comment: well i have checked the MY_Model they are not checking db group any where you have to set database connection your self in the model, $this->db->database($this->_db_group, TRUE)